# Filter one pyspark dataframe using the entries from another dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes, one of which from where the `Category` have to filtered and another one is from the conditional filtering it does.

Dataframe 1: Which has the condition

```
Earning    Age      House size    Family   ..10 more columns with no values(empty)

Avg        Low       Avg           <Empty>
```

Using this `dataframe_1` above, I have to filter the `Category` from the `dataframe_2` which satisfies the condition given in `dataframe_1`

```
Category  Age      House size    Family   Earning   .... more columns
  01      High       Avg          Low      Low
  02      Low        Avg          Avg      Avg
  03      Avg        Avg          High     High
```

Here the output will be `Category`:

`02`

as it satisfies all the condition in `dataframe_1`

I know the process of filtering in pyspark using `filter` but using single dataframe like this:

`dataframe_2.select("category").filter(col("Earning") == 'Avg').filter(col("Age") == 'Low').filter(col("House size") == 'Avg').show()`

My question is here is how to use `df_1` to filter `category` from `df_2` given any value in the `df_1` can have the filter condition and also to handle the empty values. Any leads would be helpful

Comment: you can collect to get value from dataframe 1

Comment: @Vish Can you please illustrate what you are proposing here

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this by doing left join.

Handling null values is upto your use case. But, following are some ideas on how to handle them.

1. Drop records which contain null values.
2. Replace null with most commonly present values for a particular column

Following is a sample code, *handling null values are not implemented in this code*

```
>>> df1 = spark.createDataFrame([("Avg", "Low", "Avg")], schema=["Earning", "Age", "House size"])

>>> df1.show()
+-------+---+----------+
|Earning|Age|House size|
+-------+---+----------+
|    Avg|Low|       Avg|
+-------+---+----------+

>>> df2 = spark.createDataFrame([
    ("01", "High", "Avg", "Low", "Low"),
    ("02", "Low", "Avg", "Avg", "Avg"),
    ("03", "Avg", "Avg", "High", "High")
], schema=["Category", "Age", "House size", "Family", "Earning"])

>>> df2.show()
+--------+----+----------+------+-------+
|Category| Age|House size|Family|Earning|
+--------+----+----------+------+-------+
|      01|High|       Avg|   Low|    Low|
|      02| Low|       Avg|   Avg|    Avg|
|      03| Avg|       Avg|  High|   High|
+--------+----+----------+------+-------+

>>> df3 = df1.join(df2, ["Earning", "Age", "House size"], "left")

>>> df3.show()
+-------+---+----------+--------+------+                                        
|Earning|Age|House size|Category|Family|
+-------+---+----------+--------+------+
|    Avg|Low|       Avg|      02|   Avg|
+-------+---+----------+--------+------+

>>> list(df3.select("Category").toPandas()["Category"])
['02']
```

Comment: This does not seem to be an ideal way. As I said `df1` can be dynamic and filter can be on any column so can not specify fixed column names in `join`. Also second point is converting to pandas lee down the prospect of utilising the prospect of parallelisation